# Get a value from an object dynamincally

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, for-loop, object

I would like to pass a context from the server to the client for the client to take a value inside an object more dynamically.

The server passes an object with a value for example: `"booking__validating_carrier__iata": "Cia"`.

`booking__validating_carrier__iata` translates into an array `['booking', 'validating_carrier', 'iata']` and the idea is to get `order['booking']['validating_carrier']['iata']` or `order.booking.validating_carrier.iata`

With this I would like to get into an object. The only way I could think of was:

```js
if(arr.length === 1) {
  order[arr[0]]
} else if(arr.length === 2) {
  order[arr[0]][arr[1]]
} else if(arr.length === 3) {
  order[arr[0]][arr[1]][arr[2]]
} else if(arr.length === 4) {
  order[arr[0]][arr[1]][arr[2]]
} else if(arr.length === 5) {
  order[arr[0]][arr[1]][arr[2]][arr[3]]
}
```

But isn't there a way to loop over the length of the array to go deeper in the object?

Thanks!

Comment: You could do this with a recursive function

Answer (score 1):

You could [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the array with `order` as the `initialValue` parameter. This will get the nested object as the accumulator in each iteration

```
arr.reduce((acc, k) => acc[k] || {}, order)
```

Here's a snippet:

```js
const nested = {
  "1": {
    "1.1": {
      "1.1.1": "3 level nesting"
    },
    "1.2": "2 level nesting"
  }
}

const getValue = (order, arr) => arr.reduce((acc, k) => acc[k] || {}, order)

console.log( getValue(nested, ["1", "1.1", "1.1.1"]) )
console.log( getValue(nested, ["1", "1.2"]) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a recursive function like so. It will stop when the array has no more data fields, or the object has no more nested objects which match the array fields.

```js
const arr = ['booking', 'validating_carrier', 'iata'];

const order = {
  booking: {
    validating_carrier: "test"
  }
}

const recFunc = (el, arr, i) => {
  if(arr[i] != undefined && el[arr[i]] != undefined) {
    return recFunc(el[arr[i]], arr, ++i);
  } else {
    return el;
  }
}

console.log(recFunc(order, arr, 0));
```

Or a for loop if that is more your style:

```js
const arr = ['booking', 'validating_carrier', 'iata'];

const order = {
  booking: {
    validating_carrier: "test"
  }
}

let result = order;
for(field of arr) {
  if(result[field] != undefined) {
    result = result[field];
  }
}

console.log(result);
```